# Maven dependency scope. How to understand where this dependency can be used?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

if dependencee tree looks like this:

[image]

please clarify where can I use classes from `F` dependency ?

and point me to materials for researching this thing, please.

Answer (score 2):

Classes defined in `F` are *transitively* available in `A` and `B` (and directly available in `E`).  Most people would advocate adding `F` as a direct dependency if you want build reliability. This allows you to choose the version yourself.

In Maven, the "nearest" definition wins, which means that if you declare a dependency upon `F` in `A`, then that is the version that goes into the classpath, regardless of what `E` requires. This can get complicated quickly - who knows whether `E` can cope with `F-1.3.0`, when it demands `F-1.2.2`? You end up relying on software authors to do a good job of maintaining backwards compatibility.

The [normal dependency documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) is a good place to start reading up on this. Also `mvn dependency:tree` can be useful for examining dependencies in a project.

Comment: Note: unless F is scoped such that it is in fact not transitively available of course, such as marking it provided. I mention that since I spot the word "scope" in the title even though dependency scope is not referenced in any way in the question itself.

Comment: @Gimby I am not sure that I have understood your thought. please clarify in answer

Comment: @gstackoverflow If you read the page I linked to, it explains what the "provided" scope means.

Comment: @Duncan Can I explicitly forbid transitive for dependency(without provided scope)?

Comment: According my picture if F dependency has provided scope. Is this dependency is availible in E only?

Comment: That is indeed a side effect of marking a dependency as provided.

Comment: I have heard something about excluding

Comment: @gstackoverflow You can use the Maven enforcer plugin to force you to define versions for all transitive dependencies. You can also add an `<exclusions>` block to any dependency declaration to avoid adding that dependency to the classpath.

Comment: **exclusions** is it only prevents adding dependency in classpath or is it affected on local repository?